# How can I pass props to base component in styled-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

As an example, let's say I've a component that can take in props like this:

```
const testComponent = (props: {isBold: boolean}) => {
   if(props.isBold)
     return <strong><div>hello</div></strong>
   return <div>hello</div>
    
}
```

In this case, my example component that can take in props and the result depends on the props given to it.

Now, if I extend this component in styled-components, how can I pass my props into the base component? The idea is something like this:

```
const styledTestComponent = styled(testComponent({isBold: true}))`
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5
    /* etc etc... */
`
```

Well, obviously not going to work. This part will fail: `styled(testComponent({isBold: true}))`

But the idea is that what I want to do is to use CSS to style a particular instance of a component. So in that case, I will need to pass a pre-defined props to the base component, `testComponent`.

How can I achieve this?

## **Update:**

I've come up with a quick example to illustrate the issue. The code below attempts to style a react component `MyCustomImage` as a styled-component `StyledMyCustomImage`. When this is run, you can see that `StyledMyCustomImage` does render itself as `MyCustomImage`. However, the CSS styles are not applied.

```
const MyCustomImage = props => (
  <img
    src={`https://dummyimage.com/${props.width}x${props.height}/619639/000000`}
  />
);

const StyledMyCustomImage = styled(MyCustomImage)`
  border: 2px dotted red;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Test passing props from styled component to base component</h3>
      <StyledMyCustomImage width="600" height="400" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've created a sandbox for this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/k21462vjr5

## Update 2:

Oh! Thanks to @SteveHolgado's answer, I've gotten it to work! I didn't know styled component will pass the CSS as a prop to its base component! Here's the code after adding in the class name for future reference:

```
const MyCustomImage = props => (
  <img
    src={`https://dummyimage.com/${props.width}x${props.height}/619639/000000`}
    className={props.className}
  />
);

const StyledMyCustomImage = styled(MyCustomImage)`
  border: 2px dotted red;
`;
```

The sadnbox of the working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/j4mk0n8xkw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
const StyledTestComponent = styled(testComponent)`
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5
    /* etc etc... */
`
```

and pass the prop to instance in this way.

```
<StyledTestComponent isBold />
```

Feedbacks are welcome. I have not checked it working, but feels it will work

Note: I checked and it's working. Should work for you.

Comment: I just tried it out. While the props do get passed on, the styles in StyledTestComponent doesn't get applied. In fact, when I view the source of the page, those styles are not on the page at all.

Comment: I've updated my question with an example to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `styled` function like that, your wrapped component will get passed a prop called **className**, which you need to apply to the element that you want the styles to affect:

```
const testComponent = (props) => {
  return <div className={props.className}>hello</div>
}
```

You will have access to all props in your styles, which you can use like this:

```
const styledTestComponent = styled(testComponent)`
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-weight: ${props => props.isBold ? "bold" : "normal"};

  /* etc etc... */
`
```

Comment: Thank you! I've gotten it to work now! I've also updated my question with your answer in my example code.

Comment: Just a heads up @Carven you shouldn't put the answers inside the question and leave the answers on the page as it confuses the users.